# Inequality with unknown constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Given a is a constant (positive integer), $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{3}$. Find the minimum and the maximum of:

$$P = \sqrt{4a^2+\frac{a^2 x^2}{4a^2-2a\sqrt{3}x+x^2}}$$

The problem seems hard for me since I can't even simplify $P$ (due to $a$ is an unknown constant). I took many attempts but I can't find a clean solution to this. How do I approach this?

Comment: Maximizing $P$ or $P^2$ is the same for $x$

Comment: Are you sure the range for $x$ is not $0 \le x \le a\sqrt 3$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximizing $P$ or $P^2$ is same for $x$. And to maximize for minimze $P$ , since $4a^2$ is constant and thus we only need to maximize/minimize for the fraction term :
$k=\frac{a^2 x^2}{4a^2-2a\sqrt{3}x+x^2}$

Differentiating wrt $x$ we obtain $\frac{dk}{dx}=\frac{8a^4x-2a^3\sqrt3x^2}{(4a^2-2a\sqrt{3}x+x^2)^2}$.Now ,  $\frac{dk}{dx} \ge0$ for $0\le x \le \sqrt3$. Hence maximum value is obtained at $x=\sqrt3$ and minimum value is obtained at $x=0$. Now, you can proceed from here to calculate the maximum/minimum values of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

When $P$ is a maximum, $P^2$ is also a maximum. So let $Q=P^2$.

$Q=4a^2+\dfrac{a^2 x^2}{4a^2-2a\sqrt{3}x+x^2}$
$\dfrac {\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dx}=-\dfrac{(4 \sqrt 3 - 2 a) a^3 x}{(4 a^2 - 2 \sqrt 3 a + x^2)^2}$

So our turning point lies on $x=0$. As there are no other turning points, $x=\sqrt 3$ is the point to take in consideration as for $x \ge 0$, our function is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

$P(0)=2a$ and $P(\sqrt3)= \dfrac {a\sqrt {217}}7$ so the minimum value of $P$ is $P=2a$ and the maximum value of $P$ is $P= \dfrac {a\sqrt {217}}7$.